# Significance of Super?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me why we need the super in every method for e.g.:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I am confused about the `super` keyword....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the method of the parent class.

This is the rule when you override the method of the superclass, so that you can make sure that code in the superclass get executed and behave correctly.

**Note**: Sometimes, you call super in the beginning of the method, some other times, in the end of the method

Answer (score 2):

`[super ...]` calls the implementation of the method in your class's superclass. It is important to use if the inheriting class wants to *extend* the method implementation (i.e., add something to it but also do what the superclass did) as opposed to *replacing* the method implementation.

As such, you do not call `super` in every method you override but only where it is appropriate. If you should, must or must not call `super` in a specific method should be mentioned in the documentation of that method.